# Using DPD/LAMMPS how does a protein remains a protein although there are no attractive forces in DPD?

Tags: lammps, coarse-grained

I am new to LAMMPS/DPD (Dissipative particle dynamics), but as i read through DPD model there are three main forces between beads (beads are the spheres consisting of a group of atoms). FC which is a repulsive force, Random and dissipative force.

My question is, how a protein remains as a protein by maintaining its chain-like shape if there is no attractive forces defined between its beads?

Comment: According to wikipedia there are three types of non-bonded forced. Non-bonded is the key word. There are still bond forces.

Comment: Hi Delaram, how did this go? Did you figure out the answer? Please update us!

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP responds to questions/suggestions in the comments.